# Create a signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to find values for $\alpha$ so that $\mu$ is a signed measure on $([0,1],\mathfrak{B}\cap[0,1])$ with $\mu([0,x])=x^{\alpha}\sin(\log(x))$. $\mathfrak{B}$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

I know that $\alpha$ has to be in $(0,\infty)$ so that $\mu(A)$ can't be both $\infty$ and -$\infty$, but I'm stuck on finding values for $\alpha$ so that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive.
Thanks for any hints!